# How to activate :focus on the input+button when a user click into the input?

Tags: javascript, css, button, input, focus

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 my-1">

            <form action="?p=pesquisa" method="post" value="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <div class="input-group">

                    <input class="form-control searchInput" id="cxnome" name="cxnome" type="text" placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-label="Search" style="border-right: none;" required="required">

                    <button type="submit" name="pesquisar" class="input-group-append searchInput">

                        <div class="input-group-text searchInput"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>

                    </button>            

                </div>

            </form>

        </div>
```

CSS:

```
button[type="submit"]:focus{box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);}
input[type="text"]:focus{box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(255,255,255, 0.3);}
```

I'm using this css, but i want that the input+button get the :focus no matters if the user click on the input or on the button.

This is what i want:

[image]

Comment: if the button never does anything... use a label, not a button. If the button fire logic like launch the search you need js for this purpose.  So you need to explain more.

Comment: @RaúlMartín Yea, the button is used. So i can do it only with js? How can i do it? The script is hard to make? I'm not familiar with js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to apply styles in those elements when one is focused.

You can check this:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within
- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/focus-within/

But the support isn't great. So you have to use something like this in javascript (this example using jquery)

```
$("#wrapper .input, #wrapper .button")
  .focus(function() {
    $("#wrapper").addClass("focus");
  })
  .blur(function() {
    $("#wrapper").removeClass("focus");
  });
```

I created and example here: https://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/QVmJqB

Comment: Thank you!! I'm using bootstrap 4, and the `class="form-control"` are disturbing the effect. As you can see https://codepen.io/Susi0101/pen/NLYemP, do you know how to solve it? Thank you anyway!!

Comment: no problem, happy to help. What about something like this: https://codepen.io/luarmr/pen/ZMxZEE